# Video Surveillance Server Software

Tags: security, video, streaming

My company has about 25 cameras around our property and we need a server to store any motion on each of the cameras. We are currently using a software called "Digital Video Witness" which is fairly unimpressive. We are looking for a good server software that can run all day long and easily output segments of video to a thumb drive or DVD.

Can anyone make any recommendations on good software can use, and possibly share your experience with your server hardware as well?

Comment: What OS are you hoping to run this on?

Comment: Open to anything at this point...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten around to installing it yet, but ZoneMinder is supposed to be pretty good.  They even have a livecd you can download to see how you like it.  Linux based and may be overkill, but should be able to get the job done.  Free and OpenSource.  I think any extra scripting or mods are done in PERL.

http://www.zoneminder.com/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows OS, check http://www.blueirissoftware.com/, I used it in a small office for 4 IP cameras.
You can use up to 64 cameras and is cheap 30$.
And you can have a 15-day free trial for tests.
My server had 1TB drive for videos. Images were kept for 30days and removed automatically.

I have used zoneminder, but, I could not make it work with all TV tunners I have. I have used 4 channels PCI cards with success.
If you make it work with your cards, is a great software.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have used BlueIris and was pretty happy with it. I ended up moving to [BlueCherry](http://www.bluecherrydvr.com/) because I prefer Linux/Unix as a host OS and because I wanted to use BlueCherry's 16 port card.